# robot framework : with list i have this error : ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Tags: list, xpath, robotframework

i would select an item (le chateau dans le ciel) in my list but i have this error :     ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
i do this :
~ wait until keyword succeeds    2 minutes    2s    click element   xpath=//select[@id="IDTblabla"]

```
wait until keyword succeeds    2 minutes    2s    click element   xpath=//option[contains(text(),'le chateau dans le ciel')]`
```

and the html code is :
`<div class="row"> <div class="col-xs-12"> <label for="IDTBLABLA" class="control-label">blabla</label> <div class="select2-container form-control select2-dropdown-open select2-container-active select2-drop-above" id="s2id_IDTBLABLA" tabindex="67"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">    <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-40">Standard</span> <abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>    <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation"> <b role="presentation"></b> </span> </a> <label for="s2id_autogen40" class="select2-offscreen">Bla bla</label> <div class="tooltipWrapper"> <input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-40" id="s2id_autogen40" tabindex="68" disabled=""> </div> </div> <select class="form-control select2-offscreen" id="IDTNATRGL" tabindex="70" title="blabla"> <option value="100">goldorak</option> <option value="101">nicky larson</option> <option value="102">totoro</option> <option value="103">nausicaa</option> <option value="104">remi sans famille</option> <option value="105" class="hideSelect2Option">le chateau dans le ciel</option>` 
`wait until keyword succeeds    2 minutes    2s    click element   xpath=//select[@id="IDTblabla"]

```
wait until keyword succeeds    2 minutes    2s    click element   xpath=//option[contains(text(),'le chateau dans le ciel')]`
```

i would like see in my list 'le chateau dans le ciel' selected

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the web page looks like but I created a html page based on your html code and used it on the Robot script. When it comes to selecting options from the drop down list, I find `Browser Library` easier compared to the `Selenium Library`. Using the below Robot script, I was able to select the *le chateau dans le ciel* option:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Browser

*** Variables ***
${URL}    file:///C:/Development/robot-scripts/test_cases/test.html

*** Test Cases ***
Select correct option
    New Browser    chromium    headless=false
    New Context    viewport={'width': 1920, 'height': 1080}
    New Page       ${URL}
    Wait For Elements State    text=blabla    visible    timeout=5s    message=Text 'blabla' was not visible.
    Select Options By    id=IDTNATRGL    text    le chateau dans le ciel
```

Browser library (Select Options By) documentation: https://marketsquare.github.io/robotframework-browser/Browser.html#Select%20Options%20By

Comment: Thank you. I Think that my pb comes of dom rebuilding. The dom is not stable and 4 times, i though that the pb was resolved. In fact, the test pass x times and x+1 times it failed